# initialization problem while filling a struct in c

Tags: c, struct, gcc-warning

I have a problème while filling my structure in c. The. goal of my programme is to test magical numbers in files to know their "type".
My struct look like this :

```
struct mn {
        char code[6];
        char name[30];
};
```

and I fill the struct doing this :

```
struct mn all_mn[7] = {
    [0].code = {75, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    [0].name = "ZIP",
    [1].code = {0x37, 0x7A, 0xBC, 0xAF, 0x27, 0x1C},
    [1].name = "7z",
    [2].code = {0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46, 0x2D, 0},
    [2].name = "PDF",
    [3].code = {0x49, 0x44, 0x33, 0, 0, 0},
    [3].name = "MP3",
    [4].code = {0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00, 0, 0},
    [4].name = "TIFF(little endian)",
    [5].code = {0x4D, 0x4D, 0x00, 0x2A, 0, 0},
    [5].name = "TIFF(big endian)",
    [6].code = {0x23, 0x21, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    [6].name = "shebang"};
```

I actually have no error with

```
struct mn all_mn[X] = {[X].code ....}
```

but my gcc say :

```
tp1_nico.c:24:5: error: missing initializer for field 'name' of 'struct mn' [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
   24 |     [0].name = {'Z', 'I', 'P'},
      |     ^
tp1_nico.c:19:14: note: 'name' declared here
   19 |         char name[30];
      |              ^~~~
```

for each .name in struct and I don't know why.
I'd be glad if someone can. explain it to me.

Comment: What version is your gcc? My gcc didn't complain about it.

Comment: It s gcc 7.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct mn all_mn;
```

is not an array anymore and you cant use indexes: `[0].name = {'Z', 'I', 'P'},`

the correct initialization is : `struct mn all_mn = {.name = {'Z', 'I', 'P'}};`

Comment: my bad it s. not like that actually I do not fill the struct like that I only do this : ```.             
struct mn all_mn[7] = {
    [0].code = {75, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    [0].name = "ZIP",
    [1].code = {0x37, 0x7A, 0xBC, 0xAF, 0x27, 0x1C},
    [1].name = "7z",
    [2].code = {0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46, 0x2D, 0},
    [2].name = "PDF",
    [3].code = {0x49, 0x44, 0x33, 0, 0, 0},
    [3].name = "MP3",
    [4].code = {0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00, 0, 0},
    [4].name = "TIFF(little endian)",
 ```